# Al digitar un "ID" dentro de un TextBox Mostrar un Label con el titulo de ese "ID"

Tags: asp.net

Contexto: Tengo un formulario y requiero que un vez llene con un "ID" un textbox(En este caso el textbox Editorial) me traiga el titulo asociado a ese "ID", estoy estoy utilizando Asp.net y me encuentro realizando lo dicho anteriormente pero no logro dar solución.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El label que deseo propinar para que muestre el titulo se encuentra escondido arriba de el textbox Editorial.
Mi codigo HTML:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <br />

    <table class="Tabla_Estructura" align="center" style="margin-left: 650px">
        <center align="center">
                 <div class="alert alert-info" style="text-align:center;margin-left:400px;margin-right:400px;margin-top:150px">
    <strong>AGREGAR: </strong> NUEVO LIBRO.
  </div>

            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblnombreeditor" runat="server" Style="margin-left:225px; background-color:#F7DC6F; padding:5px" Text="este es un label"></asp:Label>
        <tr align="center">
            <td class="auto-style20" style="width: 148px; height: 37px;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" CssClass="Texto" Text="Titulo :" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style29" style="height: 37px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txttitulo" MaxLength="80" Style="border-radius: 5px" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="133px" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style14" style="height: 37px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="Texto" Text="Editorial :" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12" style="height: 37px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txteditorial" MaxLength="100" Style="border-radius: 5px"  runat="server" Height="25px" Width="130px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12" style="height: 37px">
                <div class="container">
                    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" style="margin-right: 990px" data-target="#myModal">Ayuda Editores</button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">

                            <!-- Modal content-->
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Editores</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropEditor" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="NOMEDI" DataValueField="CODEDI"></asp:DropDownList>
                                    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:CadenaConexion %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [CODEDI], [NOMEDI] FROM [EDITORES]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnSeleccion" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Seleccionar" OnClick="btnSeleccion_Click" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr align="center">
            |

            <td class="auto-style14" style="height: 37px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" CssClass="Texto" Text="Autor :" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12" style="height: 37px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtautor" Style="border-radius: 5px" MaxLength="50" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="130px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style14" style="height: 37px">
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="Texto" Text="Ubicacion: " Style="margin-right: 5px" Font-Size="10pt"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12" style="height: 37px">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtubicacion" Style="border-radius: 5px" MaxLength="20" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="130px" onkeypress="return solonumeros(event)" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <td style="margin-left: 500px" align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="BtnAgregar" type="button" Style="padding: 9px; border-radius: 5px" class="button button1" runat="server" Text="Agregar" OnClick="AgregarLibro_Click" /><br />
        </td>

    </table>

</asp:Content>
```

Mi codigo aspx.cs:

```
namespace ProyectoBiblioteca.Mantenciones
{
    public partial class NuevoLibro : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        string Titulo;
        string Editorial;
        string Autor;
        string Ubi;
        int numero;
        string CadenaConexion = MasterPage.CadenaConexion;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                txteditorial.Enabled = false;
                lblnombreeditor.Visible = false;
            }

        }
        protected void AgregarLibro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txttitulo.Text != "" || txteditorial.Text != "" || txtautor.Text != "" || txtubicacion.Text != "")
            {

                Titulo = txttitulo.Text;
                Editorial = txteditorial.Text;
                Autor = txtautor.Text;
                Ubi = txtubicacion.Text;
                PrepararAcceso.AgregarEjemplar(Titulo, Editorial, Autor, Ubi, numero, CadenaConexion);
                Response.Write("<script >alert('Libro " + ObtenerCod() + " ingresado Correctamente');location.href = 'Libros.aspx';</script>");

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script >alert('Los campos no deben estar vacios, intentelo nuevamente');location.href = 'NuevoLibro.aspx';</script>");
            }

        }

        public string ObtenerCod()
        {
            System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
            PrepararAcceso.ObtenerDatos("SELECT MAX(CODLIB) AS CODIGO FROM EJEMPLAR", ref ds, MasterPage.CadenaConexion.ToString());
            string codigo = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CODIGO"].ToString();

            return codigo;
        }
        protected void btnSeleccion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string select = DropEditor.SelectedValue;
            string nombre = DropEditor.SelectedItem.ToString();
            lblnombreeditor.Text = nombre.ToString();
            txteditorial.Text = select.ToString();
            lblnombreeditor.Visible = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Si me pueden orientar en como realizar este requerimiento, si a través de un botón o alguna clase,método que puedan ayudarme a lograr el requerimiento , guías, links, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida!